# Searching depending on the category with filters

Tags: php, search, filter, search-engine, concept

What is the best practice to do a searching form with filters, where the filters are depending on the category?
e.g.:If you go to visit the ebay and select a category then the filters are different on the left hand side in the cell phones (filters: brand, operating system...)  or the fashion category (filters: size, color...)...

**In my mind** I would do more table in DB. Each table for one category (cat_cellphone, cat_fashion...). Then put a product one of these tables depending on the category (not one products table where one column contains the category ID).
These tables are different where the columns names are characterized by the category.
Next, should do more searching forms and call a form where the filter belongs to the category.

Is it a good concept or there is an other accepted practice in big projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using multiple tables to store your products isn't a good idea. Because there will be products that overlap in categories which would result storing the same product in more than one table.

Just use a product table with the ID, product_number, description, etc. and a category table to store the different categories. Then you could link them directly like:

Product table:

```
ID product_number description category
1  00001          Screwdriver 1
```

Category table:
ID description
1  Tools

And you could even expand the category table with an extra column to use subcategories by addressing the parent of the subcategory:

Category table with subcategories:

```
ID description      parent
1  Tools            NULL
2  Automatic tools  1
```

And if you don't like directly linking to the category table from the product table you could use a link table:

Product_category:

```
Product_ID Category_ID
1          1
```

Hope this answers your question.

Edit, added filter table:

To add filtering for a product you can use a table for a the filters and a link table, like so:

Filter:

```
Filter_ID description value
1         brand       Bosch
2         brand       Bahco
3         type        Phillips
```

Product_Filter:

```
Product_ID Filter_ID
1          1
1          3
```

That way you can link more than one filter to each product and use the same filter more than once.

You could even expand this further by using another table for the filter values, but that could make things a bit to complicated:

Filter:

```
Filter_ID description value
1         brand       1
```

Filter_value:

```
Filter_ID value
1         Bosch
2         Bahco
```

Comment: But If I use one product table then I would store here all of the information for the filters (one description / one column) e.g: ID Product_Number Name Operating_System Color Brand, and which does not describe the product will empty?

Comment: @Gery I've added the filters

Comment: It's not as easy as I thought. "Head scratching"

Comment: @Gery If you want to easily structure your database, you're forced to use such a construction like mine, else you need to put everything in one table which would result in a lot of columns, then this is one of the easiest ways that I know off. I hope this will help you further, if so, could you mark my answer as the right one?

Comment: Will it the right one because the longer and understandable comment. But leave a little time to the others :)

Comment: What I don't know yet, that where I should store the product descriptions (brand, price, color, OS...etc)? If not in the product table due to the lot of columns...

Comment: @Gery you could use the filters table for that or call it the properties table, because it's a property of the product, later you can use it to filter on, it's just a name

Comment: yeah, I'm beginning to understand it

Answer (score 3):

No, having multiple tables is a bad idea.

In general. use a table with a primary key over two columns instead.
(The primary key may span more than one column.)

The columns would be categoryname / filtername.

If you don't like such primary keys, and always use an autoincrement column, you can still create an index over the two columns.

The columns would be: id / categoryname / filtername / filtertext

Comment: What about the filters? Where sould I store the product description to the filters?